# Handle activemq-spring connection errors

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have configured (with spring) my application to listen to a jms que with activemq, and everything works fine.
My activemq server is installed on another server and sometime it can go offline and I would like to handle the connection error. Is that possible?

Here is my spring configuration

```
    <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:61616" />
    <bean id="messageConverter" class="com.unic.thesting.main.jms.message.TheStingMessageConverter" scope="tenant"/>
    <jms:listener-container concurrency="10" connection-factory="thestingJmsFactory" destination-type="queue" message-converter="thestingMessageConverter">
        <jms:listener destination="in" ref="orderStatusConsumer" method="consume"/>
    </jms:listener-container>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" scope="tenant">
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="messageConverter" />
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory" scope="tenant">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                    <ref local="jmsFactory" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` which gets registered when you use ` handles recovering connections to the JMS provider if it gets dropped for any reason (it by default retries every 5 seconds until the connection is restored), so you don't have to do anything on the listener front.

On the sending side with jmsTemplate, you would receive a runtime `org.springframework.jms.JmsException` if there is any issues in sending a message. You should be able to catch it for any custom processing